# Multiple ListViews and onClick problem by finding out which ListViews is clicked

Tags: android, listview

i am not very familiar with android coding so try to help me on a easy way.

The problem:
I have 2 Listviews and a onClick event handler.
How can i find out on which listview the user currently clicked?

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
'Approach: if listview1 is clicked then FUNCTION1() else FUNCTION2()'}
```

thx!

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `onListItemClick()` is the `ListView`.

Also, since only one `ListView` will be handled by `ListActivity` (and therefore routed to `onListItemClick()`), your other `ListView` will have a dedicated `OnItemClickListener`.